# 2 columns layout with different views: 100%:0% , 70%:30%, 0%:100%

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is a HTML/CSS structure/position issue, it's probably a quicky and I just missed something. Been on it for days now...can't figure it out.

I have a feed of info that I display in almost full width, when I click a button, I want a second panel to slide in from the right to a ratio of ~68/28 and if I click another button, the right panel takes the full width.

I tried a bunch of things, position relative, floats...but I can't seem to figure it out. And ideally would be using the CSS "position" attribute to make the animation smooth using CSS3.

It seems I'm really bad at positioning stuff.

Here is the HTML, plain and simple:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-left">Some content here from left col</div>
    <div class="col-right">Some content ehre from right col</div>
</div>
```

and the CSS that doesn't work:

```
.container{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    padding: 0 40px;
    right: 0;
}

.col-left. col-left{
    position: relative;
    display: block;  
    top:0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}

.col-left{
    left:0px;
}
.col-right{
     right: -100%;  
}

body.split .col-left{   
}

body.split .col-right{
}
```

Here is a Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5zG3q/21/
(as you can see, I'm already on v21 of Fiddle and still can't figure it out)

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDITS**
After some tweaking, I got something closer to what I want, but it feels dirty...
http://jsfiddle.net/5zG3q/23/

Comment: To note, the columns have different heights...so the parent element kind of needs to know that...

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand the question, but is this more what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/YABD6/

Comment: I updated the fiddle a little. Maybe will make more sense. http://jsfiddle.net/5zG3q/21/

Comment: But basically, I have a main container, inside that container, I would like 2 divs (to always be side by side and not on top of each other). By default, you only see the first column. Click a button the 2nd column slides in from the right, click a another button the 2nd column takes full width.

Comment: @drew_w : Nice, seems to be working. Any chance of getting the slide animation? Also because the width of the right-col is 0% on hidden it makes the parent div super mega high.

Comment: @drew_w Updated the Fiddle a bit, was in the wrong order. This is exactly what I was looking for. Just need the animation if you have any ideas. http://jsfiddle.net/YABD6/6/

Comment: So in some ways, it would look like an image slider. First you see the first col full width. Click. See 70% first col and 30% second col. Click see second col full width. But with smooth animation as if it's gliding from left to right smoothly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After from inspiration from @drew_w and from other post, I think I found the solution. 
I added a wrapping DIV around the col that was twice the width. 
Then the divs ratios, I had to divide by 2 obviously. Then I could just play with the widths and the positions to have the animation.

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 60px;
    padding: 0 40px;
    right: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#e2e2e2;
}
.inner-container{
    display: block;
    width: 200%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.col-left,  .col-right {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}
.col-left {
    width: 50%;
    background: green;
}
.col-right {
    margin-left: 10%;
    width: 29%;
    background: red;
}
body.split .col-left {
    width: 33%;
}
body.split .col-right {
    margin-left: 1%;
    width: 15%;
}
body.full .col-left {    
    width: 33%;
    margin-left: -33%;
}
body.full .col-right {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Had to add a bit of JS that adds a class to the body:

```
$("body").on("click", "[data-toggle-view]", function () {    
    var $this = $(this);
    var $body = $("body");
    var view = $this.data("toggleView");
    $body.removeClass("split full");
    $body.addClass(view);
    return false;
});
```

Here is the Fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/5zG3q/23/

Still doesn't feel very clean, but it works.